# How to filter MongoDB docs for nested array/object/array items

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, nested, mongodb-compass

I need to filter documents containing `"Pulse"` in the `to_do` Array.

I want to find this doc:

```
_id: 627a8f017991aa0004765052
chapters: Array
    0 : Object
        team_oid: 62754ff055aa93f004befb2c
        to_do: Array
            0 "Chapter"
            1 "Pulse"
```

But ignore this one:

```
_id: 627a8f017991aa0004765052
chapters: Array
    0 : Object
        team_oid: 62754ff055aa93f0d4befb2c
        to_do: Array
            0 "Chapter"
```

The problem is the Array / Object / Array nesting... I've been trying $elemMatch, but all examples only show nested Array / Array... The object in the middle is confusing.

Comment: `.find({"chapters.to_do": "Pulse"})`?

Comment: Perfect. Make it an answer and I'll accept.